# How to set the color of the inside of checkbox - asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to set the inside color of a checkbox (the part that's usually white, waiting to be ticked \ checked). How can I set that to a different color, not the default?

Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with css. Forms are notoriously hard to style ([technical explanation from Eric Meyer](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/15/formal-weirdness/)).

You can, however, use javascript to completely replace the checkbox with an image yet still keep the form encoding of a normal checkbox element. [Here's an example using jquery](http://uniformjs.com/)

Comment: interesting, no other solution? rather not js for this

Comment: I changed the link to point to a better and more modern example. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Sub SetColor()
    Try
        For i As Integer = 0 To gvMaster.Rows.Count - 1
            FN = gvMaster.Rows(i).Cells(3).Text
            If FN = "Present" Then
                gvMaster.Rows(i).Cells(3).ForeColor = Color.Green
            End If
            If FN = "Absent" Then
                gvMaster.Rows(i).Cells(3).ForeColor = Color.Red
            End If

            AN = gvMaster.Rows(i).Cells(4).Text
            If AN = "Present" Then
                gvMaster.Rows(i).Cells(4).ForeColor = Color.Green
            End If
            If AN = "Absent" Then
                gvMaster.Rows(i).Cells(4).ForeColor = Color.Red
            End If
        Next
    Catch generatedExceptionName As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```